# Selected highest value within last quarter or most recent within last 4 quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table that I am trying to select the the highest values per site for the past quarter, and if there isn't one, the most recent value within the past 4 quarters.

```
MaxOfDate   sys_loc_code    chemical_name       Result    
------------------------------------------------------
    6/23/2020   ALTAIR 1    Tetrachloroethene   NULL 
    12/23/2019  ALTAIR 1    Tetrachloroethene   2.2    
    6/10/2019   ALTAIR 10   Tetrachloroethene   1.8
    6/8/2019    ALTAIR 10   Tetrachloroethene   5.5    
    4/24/2019   ALTAIR 10   Tetrachloroethene   3.0    
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 1S   Tetrachloroethene   NULL
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 2    Tetrachloroethene   0.5 
    3/18/2020   ALTAIR 2    Tetrachloroethene   5.0 
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 3    Tetrachloroethene   1.5  
    3/24/2020   ALTAIR 3    Tetrachloroethene   0.5    
    9/17/2019   ALTAIR 4    Tetrachloroethene   1.2 
    5/5/2019    ALTAIR 4    Tetrachloroethene   3.5
    4/18/2019   ALTAIR 4    Tetrachloroethene   2.8
    6/23/2020   ALTAIR 5    Tetrachloroethene   4.7
    3/5/2020    ALTAIRN5    Tetrachloroethene   7.4
    12/17/2019  ALTAIR 5    Tetrachloroethene   2.9
    9/11/2019   ALTAIR 5    Tetrachloroethene   8.5
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 6    Tetrachloroethene   NULL
    6/23/2020   ALTAIR 7    Tetrachloroethene   NULL  
    9/11/2019   ALTAIR 7    Tetrachloroethene   1.8
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 8D   Tetrachloroethene   NULL
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 8S   Tetrachloroethene   3.1
    3/4/2020    ALTAIR 8S   Tetrachloroethene   2.4
    12/17/2019  ALTAIR 8S   Tetrachloroethene   NULL
    9/10/2019   ALTAIR 8S   Tetrachloroethene   1.2
    6/23/2019   ALTAIRN 9D  Tetrachloroethene   NULL   
    5/11/2019   ALTAIRN 9D  Tetrachloroethene   1.0    
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 9S   Tetrachloroethene   NULL   
    11/13/2019  SSFSDW 309  Tetrachloroethene   20     
    10/18/2019  SSFSMW 202  Tetrachloroethene   NULL   
    10/14/2019  SSFSMW 204  Tetrachloroethene   1.2    
    10/15/2019  SSFSMW 205  Tetrachloroethene   64     
    10/23/2019  SSFSMW 207  Tetrachloroethene   24     
    11/4/2019   SSFSMW 212  Tetrachloroethene   47
```

My expected results are:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    6/23/2020   ALTAIR 1    Tetrachloroethene   NULL   Highest Q  
    6/10/2019   ALTAIR 10   Tetrachloroethene   1.8    Most recent after Q2
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 1S   Tetrachloroethene   NULL   Highest Q2
    3/18/2020   ALTAIR 2    Tetrachloroethene   5.0    Highest Q2    
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 3    Tetrachloroethene   1.5    Highest Q2
    9/17/2019   ALTAIR 4    Tetrachloroethene   1.2    Most recent after Q2
    3/5/2020    ALTAIRN5    Tetrachloroethene   7.4    Highest Q2
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 6    Tetrachloroethene   NULL   Highest Q2
    6/23/2020   ALTAIR 7    Tetrachloroethene   NULL   Highest Q2
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 8D   Tetrachloroethene   NULL   Highest Q2
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 8S   Tetrachloroethene   3.1    Highest Q2
    6/23/2019   ALTAIRN 9D  Tetrachloroethene   NULL   Most recent after Q2
    5/11/2019   ALTAIRN 9D  Tetrachloroethene   1.0    Most recent after Q2
    6/24/2020   ALTAIR 9S   Tetrachloroethene   NULL   Highest Q2
    11/13/2019  SSFSDW 309  Tetrachloroethene   20     Highest Q2
    10/18/2019  SSFSMW 202  Tetrachloroethene   NULL   Highest Q2
    10/14/2019  SSFSMW 204  Tetrachloroethene   1.2    Highest Q2
    10/15/2019  SSFSMW 205  Tetrachloroethene   64     Highest Q2
    10/23/2019  SSFSMW 207  Tetrachloroethene   24     Highest Q2
    11/4/2019   SSFSMW 212  Tetrachloroethene   47     Highest Q2
```

There should only be one record for each `sys_loc_code`. "ALTAIRN 5" Result is 7.4 is the only value I want for this site. It is the highest value for the past quarter (Q2) even though there was a later reading taken. "ALTAIR 4" should be 2.8 because it was the most recent value since no reading were taken last quarter. If it goes further back than the most recent quarter, I want the most recent value, not the highest.

The query should read something like this, for each unique sys_loc_code, if date falls in the past quarter (Q2), give me the highest value. Else give me the most recent value. Thus, one record for each unique sys_loc_code, in order of preference, 1. highest value for past quarter OR 2. the most recent date if no exists within the past quarter.

Comment: Please show your expected results. And for answer provide DDL/DML to setup the test data.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Is this what you want?

```
select oar.*
from (select oar.*,
             row_number() over (partition by oar.chemical_name, oar.sys_loc_code order by oar.result_value desc) as seqnum
      from [GMP].[GMP_Other_Agencies_Results] oar
      where oar.chemical_name = 'Tetrachloroethene' and
            oar.PrepDate >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, (month(getdate()) + 2) / 3, 1)
     ) oar
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e1f85c9321f31b9ee910fcdd8440d672) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I am getting two error messages: When I run the program, I get "Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line The year function requires 1 argument(s)." When I put mouse over dateadd function I get "The dateadd function requires 3 argument(s)." The select statement was missing its closing parenthesis so I put one after the parenthesis on line 7. Just curious, why oar? Is it an acronym for something?

Comment: @Bonneroo . . . I fixed whatever silly thing I was doing with the date and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It still did not produce what I had hoped. I did some major editing to my question above in an attempt to be clearer.